# What causes the ENOTCONN error?

Tags: sockets

I'm currently maintaining some web server software and I need to perform a lot of I/O operations. The `read()`, `write()`, `close()` and `shutdown()` calls, when used on a socket, may sometimes raise an `ENOTCONN` error. What exactly does this error mean? What are the conditions that would trigger it? I can never seem to reproduce it locally but there are users who can.

Right now I just ignore `ENOTCONN` when raised by `close()` and `shutdown()` because it seems harmless, but I'm not entirely sure.

EDIT:

- I am absolutely sure that the `connect()` call succeeded. I check for its return value.
- `ENOTCONN` is most often raised by `close()` and `shutdown()`. I've only very rarely seen a `read()` and `write()` raising `ENOTCONN`.

Comment: What operating system?  I am tracking down a similar problem at work on an old Solaris 10 system.  Thanks.

Comment: Mostly FreeBSD. In the mean time I've found out that there are kernel bugs in FreeBSD which could cause close() and shutdown() to erroneously return ENOTCONN when dealing with Unix domain sockets. Solaris also has various kernel bugs w.r.t. Unix domain sockets, although I've only observed bugs in connect().

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are sure that nothing on your side of the TCP connection is closing the connection, then it sounds to me like the remote side is closing the connection.

`ENOTCONN`, as others have pointed out, simply means that the socket is not connected. This doesn't necessarily mean that `connect` failed. The socket may well have been connected previously, it just wasn't at the time of the call that resulted in `ENOTCONN`.

This differs from:

- `ECONNRESET`: the other end of the connection sent a TCP reset packet. This can happen if the other end is refusing a connection, or doesn't acknowledge that it is already connected, among other things.
- `ETIMEDOUT`: this generally applies only to `connect`. This can happen if the connection attempt is not successful within a system-dependent amount of time.

`EPIPE` can sometimes be returned by some socket-related system calls under conditions that are more or less the same as `ENOTCONN`. For example, on some systems, `EPIPE` and `ENOTCONN` are synonymous when returned by `send`.

While it's not unusual for `shutdown` to return `ENOTCONN`, since this function is supposed to tear down the TCP connection, I would be surprised to see `close` return `ENOTCONN`. It really should never do that.

Finally, as dwc mentioned, `EBADF` shouldn't apply in your scenario unless you are attempting some operation on a file descriptor that has already been `close`d. Having a socket get disconnected (i.e. the TCP connection has broken) is not the same as closing the file descriptor associated with that socket.

Comment: You’re wrong: the other side closing the connection is not a reason for shutdown() or close() to fail. Nor does a ENOTCONN on shutdown() indicate that no RESET actually happened in reality. (See my answer for more details.)

Comment: @Robert: I don't think I said that. I only see that I said that `ENOTCONN` can be returned by `shutdown` (which is absolutely true) and that it shouldn't ever be returned by `close`, as the OP was saying he had observed (also absolutely true).

Comment: You say both, that ENOTCONN was returned because the remote side closed the connection _and_ that it differs from ECONNRESET. – I say that ENOTCONN is never returned for an ordinary remotely closed connection. I also believe that shutdown() implementations might return ENOTCONN in ECONNRESET cases, because the latter is not supposed to be returned by shutdown().

Comment: Probably the destination address or port is wrong or not listenning (other security restriccions can be preventing the connection from being succesfull)

Answer (score 2):

I believe ENOTCONN is returned, because shutdown() is not supposed to return ECONNRESET or other more accurate errors.

It is wrong to assume that the other side “just” closed the connection. On the TCP-level, the other side can only half-close a connection (or abort it). The connection is ordinary fully closed if both sides do a shutdown() (or close()). If both side do that, shutdown() actually succeeds for both of them!

The problem is that shutdown() did *not* succeed in ordinary (half-)closing the connection, neither as the first one to close it, nor as the second one. – From the errors listed in the POSIX docs for shutdown(), ENOTCONN is the least inappropriate, because the others indicate problems with arguments passed to shutdown() (or local resource problems to handle the request).

So what happened? These days, a NAT device somewhere between the two parties involved might have dropped the association and sends out RESET packets as a reaction. Reset connections are so common for IPv4, that you will get them anywhere in your code, even masked as ENOTCONN in shutdown().

A coding bug might also be the reason. On a non-blocking socket, for example, a connect() can return 0 without indicating a successful connection yet.

Comment: It has already been confirmed to be a FreeBSD kernel bug. The ENOTCONN error code was observed on Unix domain sockets so TCP could not have anything to do with it anyway.

Comment: I came across your question while looking for reasons why ENOTCONN is returned while operating on a previously connected TCP-socket. (Was not your case, but the question is still in the air.) – And I felt compelled to answer because the reason is: a (kernel) bug somewhere or an error condition of the connection, which is inappropriately labeled ENOTCONN. The reason is and was _not_  an ordinary remote connection close. That answer is incorrect for both unix domain sockets (your case) and TCP sockets (my case).

Comment: As far as I can see, shutdown() on macOS may return ENOTCONN if the other side gracefully terminated connection (i.e. called shutdown(SHUT_RDWR) + close). Both sockets are TCP on 127.0.0.1. Not sure if this is conforming to POSIX, but this happens. The same code does not produce ENOTCONN on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It's because, at the moment of shutting() the socket, you have data in the socket's buffer waiting to be delivered to the remote party which has closed() or shutted down() its receiving socket.
I don't finish understanding how sockets work, I am rather a noob, and I've failed to even find the files where this "shutdown" function is implemented, but seeing that there's practically no user manual for the whole sockets thing I started trying all possibilities until I got the error in a "controlled" environment. It could be something else, but after much trying these are the explanations I settled for:

- If you sent data after the remote side closed the connection, when you shutdown(), you get the error.
- If you sent data before the remote side closed the connection but it didn't get received() on the other end, you can shutdown() once, the next time you try to shutdown(), you get the error.
- If you didn't send any data, you can shutdown all the times you want, as long as the remote side doesn't shutdown(); once the remote side has shutdown(), if you try to shutdown() and the socket was already shutdown(), you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you've connected properly in the first place, `ENOTCONN` is most likely to be caused by either the `fd` being closed on your end (perhaps in another thread?) while you're in the middle of a request, or by the connection dropping while you're in the middle of the request.

In any case, it means that the socket is not connected. Go ahead and clean up that socket. It's dead. No problem calling `close()` or `shutdown()` on it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fd is not being closed by another thread. But suppose it is, wouldn't that cause an EBADFD instead?

Furthermore, it's often close() and shutdown() that raise ENOTCONN, not read() and write(). What would this mean?

Comment: Note in my answer I specify "in the middle of a request". So you make the call, and execution switches to another process. Then the connection drops, and your process begins executing... EBADFD was not and is not true (it's a valid fd), but you're not connected. So you get ENOTCONN.

Answer (score 0):

Transport endpoint is not connected

The socket is associated with a connection-oriented protocol and has not been connected. This is usually a programming flaw.

From: http://www.wlug.org.nz/ENOTCONN

Comment: I know the name of the error, but what does it *mean*? What is this transport endpoint that it's referring to and how is this any different from EPIPE, ECONNRESET and ETIMEDOUT?

Comment: I guess you just did not call connect() or did not check if connect() succeeded.

Comment: I did, it succeeded. Users who were reporting this problem observed that the read()s and write()s work just fine, but at shutdown() and close() time it raises ENOTCONN. I cannot reproduce it locally at all, and nor do most users experience this problem.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved by changing my node version to which it required

Comment: This question isn't specifically about Node or a particular Node sockets wrapper, so it's unlikely this will solve the problem for most other readers.